# What options do I have to build a WTL program that runs on XP and later but with latest features?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wtl

By default WTL uses defines to make features available according to the `WINVER` etc, much like `windows.h` and other Windows SDK headers, really.

This means a modern WTL application when linked can only run on XP and later, but uses exclusively the features available to XP. If you include features from newer platforms you end up with a binary that's incompatible with XP.

Is there a way to build a WTL application in such a way that on new systems it will have the modern appearance (modern common controls and common dialogs) while it can still run on XP? How would I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inability to run in XP and pre-XP systems comes from using latest Visual C++ toolsets, rather than use of recent `WINVER` values. The last C++ runtime compatible with Windows 2000 is, as far as I remember, Visual Studio 2008's "v90" - this is what you need to use (or, non-MS compiler alternatively?). For XP, you need one of the toolsets: v100, v110_xp, v120_xp. Note that "_xp" suffix means that this is alternate version of another mainstream toolset, which is however incompatible with XP.

That is, to target XP and on, you need a proper toolset and then version of Visual Studio and inclusion or non-inclusion of latest `WINVER`s don't matter.

Current release of WTL and Visual Studio versions 2008 through 2013 with proper toolset applied build valid XP compatible applications, which in the same time might include most recent SDK definitions, unlocked to you by high `WINVER` values.

The application built this way is compatible with OS versions in terms of not having static links to possibly missing dependencies. The other way, it is up you to to detect if specific feature is available in the runtime environment. For instance, if you are going to use features which require Common Controls version 6 and they are missing in XP, then you are responsible to check available features and fall back to respective code path in your code.

Comment: One can also use the WDKs, not just the SDKs or VS. This is not the point I am asking about, though. The important point is not that my build should be compatible in one direction, but that it should be in two. I'm not sure how I should word this differently in my question to make it clear, though. Basically building it with VS 2005, for example, doesn't automatically fix the issues of WTL allowing only for a single `WINVER` and behaving in an incompatible manner on XP if given a value designating Vista or 7. The CRT is of course also relevant, but this is beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: Sorry, I see you want XP and not pre-XP, I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for your time, but this still dodges my actual question. My question is not purely about being able to *run* an application in XP. I know I can do that and I know how I can do that. It is about the fact that certain `#define`s will govern what symbols the compiler sees at all (and to a lesser extent the behavior of WTL). So if I set `WINVER` to `0x600` I may get the desired modern features, but it fails to even load on XP. If I set `WINVER` to `0x501` it runs on XP but looks horrible on more modern versions of Windows. I think it's all in my question - albeit in fewer words.

Comment: Well, the rule of thumb here is as follows: `1` _xp toolset to that runtime is at all compatible with oldest OS version, `2` highest `WINVER` and friend values to unlock latest SDK definition, and finally `3` runtime detection (your responsibility) of features that might be available in more recent but not in older OSes, with appropriate UI/API changes and fallbacks.

Comment: Example of the latter: if version is Vista+ you can use newer common dialogs API for open/save file dialogs. Otherwise you are limited to `GetOpenFileName` only. However to have new API definitions available in first place you have to define WINVER high enough...

Comment: Ah, the last paragraph now touches the topic of my question. You wrote it while I wrote my comment. Yes, the Vista+ example you gave is exactly the problem I face and I'd like to know how I can work around it without having to manually declare all functions (and in WTL templates and other symbols) not available at a lower `WINVER`.

Comment: High `WINVER` values open new definitions but they don't break compatibility with older systems before you start actually using (referencing) them in your code. This is where you are left on your own and WTL itself is of little help. If you use some new stuff which breaks comatibility with older systems, you are responsible to use dynamic linking OR delay loaded DLLs OR otherwise resolve the conflicts.

Comment: Okay, so essentially there is no option other than managing all of this myself and reinventing a wheel that must have been invented a bazillion times before? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: There is no universal wheel invented to fallback to X if Y is unavailable. You have handy stuff to help: delay load DLLs, `RunTimeHelper` class in WTL's `atlapp.h`, version checking functions. That's it, not so much (delay loaded DLLs are actually very helpful).

Comment: thanks, in this case I'm going to accept your answer. Although it means I am where I started, it also means I now **know** I am not missing out on something better and easier that may exist.

Comment: The problem is that noone but developer can decide what to do in case API is missing. It is typical to wrap this into helper class with 2+ code paths - normal and compatibility fallback, but there are no wrappers for every case. Then - yes - we're where we started from.

Comment: Consider `ITaskbarList3`. No big deal for COM interfaces to query them and ignore if they don't return an instance (the conditional code paths). However, *without* setting `WINVER` to at least W7, I'm not even going to see the GUID or interface declarations. And that's a silly situation. Similarly with the API declarations you're not just missing out on the function prototype, but also on constants that are relevant to calling that function. Only part of that can be resolved by using delay loading or similar techniques.